# Exporting a file into a subdirectory of notebook

Tags: export, import, save, files-and-directories

How can I create a directory in a notebook directory and export a file (resulted from that notebook) to created subdirectory?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that by "a directory in a notebook directory" you mean "the directory of the notebook where the Export is evaluated". Of course the notebook should first be saved somewhere.
Then do :

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "newDirectory", 
   "testFile55.jpg"}], ConstantImage[Red]]
```

The "newDirectory" wil be created as part of the file creation (no need to create the directory separately first).

The Mathematica Version should not be to old.

Comment: The option `CreateIntermediateDirectories` is used to control the behavior of whether subdirectories need to be explicitly created

Comment: It shows as - Export::nodir: Directory C:\Users\v\Desktop\export mathematica\newDirectory\ does not exist.

Comment: @MalliTangi: Which version do you use? As andre314 has mentioned,the Mathematica version should not be too old for this to work. For older versions you had to create the directory yourself. That would then look like this: `filename = 
  FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "subdir", "test.jpg"}];
CreateDirectory[DirectoryName[filename], 
  CreateIntermediateDirectories -> True];
Export[filename,data];`. By the way, the extra `CreateDirectory` does of course no harm in newer versions as well...

Comment: @ Albert, thanks. I use version 12. The code works when I create a directory myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[random];
SeedRandom[12];
random = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 5}];
Export["directory like C:\\Documents\\trial.xls", random, "xls"];
```

This should export `random` matrix to `Documents` directory with a file name `trial.xls`.